# How to share live audio output from PC-1 to PC-2 over local area network?

Tags: windows, networking, audio, drivers

I have PC-1 and PC-2 quite a distance away from each other, Both are running Windows XP.
I want to be able to watch videos through PC-1 and hear audio from PC-1 and PC-2 at the same time without any delay, I have tried the stream function from VLC player but it has a 1 sec delay..

Is there anyway or any software with can send the audio directly from the sound card?

Comment: Does it have to be over the network? If so, I believe you will have a difficult time syncing the sound to remove the delay. Would a patch cable from sound `out` on the source PC-1 to the `input` on the soundcard of the other PC-2 work?

Comment: Is it too far & messy to pull the audio cable to PC 2... Is there anyway way to do this with software?